# Access nested relation while selecting specific columns for the parent relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In model relations I want to select specific columns, but that makes me lose the ability of calling other nested relation inside this one (ProductGroupPrices::class for example)

How can I specify the columns for price() relation and reach the inner relations of ProductGroupPrices::class too like currency()

```php
<?php

class ProductsGroups extends Model {   

    public function price(){
        return $this->hasOne(ProductGroupPrices::class, 'group_id')->select(['id', 'group_id', 'price'])->latest();
    } 
}
```

The other class

```php
<?php

class ProductGroupPrices extends Model { 

    public function currency(){
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Modules\Currencies\Models\Currencies::class, 'currency_id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the required column(s):

```php
public function price(){
    return $this->hasOne(ProductGroupPrices::class, 'group_id')
        ->select(['id', 'group_id', 'price', 'currency_id'])
        ->latest();                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```